# Tengo un error al buscar un correo en mysql

Tags: php

Mi intención es registrar una cuenta mediante dos tablas en una guardo el correo y la contraseña y en el otro los datos del usuario el problema sale cuando registro el correo y la contraseña y después para buscar me sale este mensaje |

Tiene un error en su sintaxis SQL; consulte el manual que corresponde a la versión de su servidor MariaDB para conocer la sintaxis correcta para usar cerca de cuentas_proveedores 'donde correo='123@gmail.com' 'en la línea 1.

---

### JAVASCRIPT

```
function proveedorRGT() {
  var card_n2Email = document.getElementById('card-n2Email').value;
  var card_n2Contrasena1 = document.getElementById('card-n2Contrasena1').value;
  var card_n2Contrasena2 = document.getElementById('card-n2Contrasena2').value;
  var card_n2Tipo = document.getElementById('card-n2Tipo').value;
  var mensaje = confirm('¿Estas seguro?');

  }
if (mensaje) {
var card_n2bdTable = 'cuentas_proveedores';
rgtAccount(card_n2Email, card_n2Contrasena1, card_n2bdTable);
}

function rgtAccount(card_n2Email, card_n2Contrasena1, card_n2bdTable) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php/rtr-user.php',
    data: ('correo='+card_n2Email+'&pass='+card_n2Contrasena1+'&tipe='+card_n2bdTable),
    success: function(result) {
      $('form#card-n2').trigger('reset');
      $('form#card-n1 #card-n1Id').val(result);
      console.log('Se envio correctamente');
    },
    error: function(result) {
      alert('ERROR AL ENVIAR DATOS AREA');
    }
  });
}
```

---

### PHP

```
<?php
include("conectinDB.php");--->Conexion a la base de datos
/* insertar formulario areas */
if (isset($_POST['correo'])!="" && isset($_POST['pass'])!="") {
 $rtrcorreo = isset($_POST['correo']) ? $_POST['correo'] : "";
 $rtrpass = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : "";
 $bdtable = isset($_POST['tipe']) ? $_POST['tipe'] : "";
 $date = date("Y-m-d");
 $mysql = conectinDB1();
 $orden = "insert into $bdtable(correo, contraseña, fecha_Registro)values('$rtrcorreo','$rtrpass','$date')";
 $insertArea = mysqli_query($mysql, $orden)or die('ERROR AL GUARDAR DATOS'.mysqli_error($mysql));
 mysqli_close($mysql);
 echo buscarCorreo($rtrcorreo, $bdtable);
}

function buscarCorreo($rtrcorreo, $bdtable){
  $mysql = conectinDB1();
  $order = "select * from '$bdtable' where correo='$rtrcorreo'";
  $ncro = mysqli_query($mysql,$order) or die("ERROR BUSCAR ELEMENTOS".mysqli_error($mysql));
  $id1 = mysqli_fetch_array($ncro) or die("ERROR EN ARRAY ELEMENTOS".mysqli_error($ncro));
  return $id1[1];
  mysqli_close($mysql);
  }

?>
```

Comment: en tu consulta , quita las comillas simples del nombre de la tabla , asi `$order = "select * from $bdtable where correo='$rtrcorreo'";`

Comment: primero debes eliminar el uso de acentos en los campos de tu base de datos esto causa problemas `contraseña`  y para lo otro debes quitar las comillitas ejemplo `"select * from {$bdtable} where correo='$rtrcorreo'"`

Comment: un consejo cuando programe deber eliminar los caracteres especiales como Ñ o letras con tildes " ñÑ á é í ó ú " para evitar cualquier error ya que se considera especiales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrige esta seccion.

```
$order = "select * from '$bdtable' where correo='$rtrcorreo'";
```

quita las comillas simples

```
$order = "select * from $bdtable where correo='$rtrcorreo'";
```

Comment: ya me salió muchas gracias Carlos Cordova.

Comment: Excelente!!, marca la respuesta como resuelta